# What are the relevant null distributions to infer the results of a simulation that renders a multinomial distribution with three possible results?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, multinomial-distribution, chi-squared-distribution

I have simulated 10 000 occurrences of a soccer match, by generating random numbers from 0 to 1, and then passing these, and the adjusted expected goals by team for the match, through an inverse Poisson function in Python. The frequencies of the results are then summarized by a function either as «home team wins», «ties» or «road team wins», in a list titled «simulated», which is a multinomial distribution with three possible outcomes.

I use these results to test the goodness of fit of the simulated distribution to null distributions, by calculating χ2 for each null distribution. I consider, and this is my main question, that the relevant null distributions are those in which either the home team wins equal the road team wins, the home team wins equal ties, the road team wins equal ties or all three results have more or less the same frequency, for instance combinations of two possibilities having 3 333 frequency and one 3 334 frequency.

These null distributions are only possible if there are two frequencies of the possible three that are equal, i.e. either: i) «i» represents an equal frequency, such that 2*i+j=10 000, or ii) «j» represents and equal frequency, such that 2*j+i=10 000. Three of the cases will also resemble a situation in which all three outcomes have more or less an equal chance, rendering two possibilities with 3 333 results and one with 3 334.
These outcomes are only possible for the first 4 999 natural integers as the values of «i» in i), or for the even numbers in the range of natural numbers from 1 to 9 998 as the values of «i» in ii). My code is the following:

```
##Counting the number of home team wins, road team wins and ties, 
##rendered by another function and summarizing in list «results»

simulated=[results.count("home team wins"),results.count("tie"),results.count("road team wins")]

##The following lists are used as the values of «i» in the null distributions.

## For the values of i in j=10 000 – 2*i
values_i =list(range(1,5000))

##For the values of i in j=5 000 – i/2
i_values=[]

for a in values_i:
        i=2*a
        i_values.append(i)

## I then calculate the critical value «cr» for the chi-distribution with alpha 0.05 and 2 
##degrees of freedom, i.e. three possibilities minus one.

import scipy
from scipy.stats import chi2

alpha = 0.05

df = 2

cr=chi2.ppf(q=1-alpha,df=df)

##This will be the list of x to compare to the critical value
x_list=[]

## There are six different possible combinations of i and j frequencies in which two results are
##equal, resulting from three different permutations and two different values for i and j,
##(10000-2*i) or (5000-2/i). I calculate lists of each of these possible distributions, as
##expected_a,_b,_c,_d,_e and _f, the corresponding χ2 for each expected list, compared to the 
##«simulated» distribution, and append the results to x_list=[]

expected_a= [[(5000-(i/2)),(5000-(i/2)),i] for i in i_values]

for i in expected_a:
        x_a = sum([(o-e)**2./e for o,e in zip(simulated,i)])
        x_list.append(x_a)

expected_b = [[(5000-(i/2)),i,(5000-(i/2))] for i in i_values]
 
for j in expected_b:
        x_b = sum([(o-e)**2./e for o,e in zip(simulated,j)])
        x_list.append(x_b)

expected_c = [[i,(5000-(i/2)),(5000-(i/2))] for i in i_values]

for k in expected_c:
        x_c = sum([(o-e)**2./e for o,e in zip(simulated,k)])
        x_list.append(x_c)

expected_d= [[(10000-(2*i)),i,i] for i in values_i]

for l in expected_d:
        x_d = sum([(o-e)**2./e for o,e in zip(simulated,l)])
        x_list.append(x_d)

expected_e= [[i,(10000-(2*i)),i] for i in values_i]

for m in expected_e:
        x_e = sum([(o-e)**2./e for o,e in zip(simulated,m)])
        x_list.append(x_e)

expected_f= [[i,i,(10000-(2*i))] for i in values_i]

for n in expected_f:
        x_f = sum([(o-e)**2./e for o,e in zip(simulated,n)])
        x_list.append(x_f)

##I conclude by testing if all values in x_list are greater than the critical value
##which means the results are significant, against all null distributions
if all(i>cr for i in x_list):
```

If this is the case, the simulation is significant, and the team with the greater frequency, within a margin of error of 2 % (another calculation to account for randomness) is forecasted as a winner. If not, one of the null hypotheses is true, and it is not possible to call a likely winner. This is also the case if frequencies are within the margin of error. Both when the null hypothesis is true, and the result is within the margin of error, the result is forecasted a tie. The most likely score, for the selected alternative, is fetched with another function, to forecast a score.

This seems to be working fine. But I have a feeling that I am missing something. Are these the relevant null distributions to test the significance of the simulation?

**Update**
I realized that I had to make a slight adjustment to the null distributions, even following my logic (which I am uncertain of). I noticed this after test runs, which were rendering some surprising results. For example, a simulated list equal to the the following frequencies [6040,2030,1930] was giving a non-significant result with the code above. This was surprising, because it implies that the home team wins 6040 matches, a number that exceeds the sum of the simulated ties (2030) plus the road team wins (1930), for a result of 3960, and this was still not considered significantly different from null distributions where it is not possible to call a winner. This made me realize that my null distributions could not include cases where either of the equal frequencies, i or j, is below the third and different frequency. In such cases, we can already be confident that the simulated distribution has called a winner. Therefore, I added a few bits of code, to make this more precise. For the lists constructed with two elements j that equal (5000-(i/2)), the condition to be met to formulate null distributions is that the different frequency i, cannot be greater than either of the equal frequencies j, or [5000-(i/2)]. I therefore added: "if i < 3334" when constructing the list of distributions, which results from solving i<5000-i/2. The exact result for real numbers is i<3333.33. But in this case, i<3334 implies values lower than 3334 starting at 3332, because i for these distributions includes only the even numbers in the range of natural integers from 1 to 9998. This generates null hypotheses just for the cases where the different frequency i is 3332 or less, and always less than either of the two equal frequencies. We are interested in testing if our simulated distribution is significantly different from such cases, because it would be a problem for calling a winner if not. In such a case, two roughly equal frequencies would be greater than the alternative. So how do we call a winner? But if the different frequency in the distribution is greater than either of the equal frequencies, we know that this is most likely the winner. When it comes to the three other lists of null distributions, constructed with two equal frequencies i and one j=(10000-2*i), we are similarly interested in formulating null distributions where either of the equal frequencies, that is i, exceeds the different value j=(10000-2*i). This is the same as saying i>3333, which is obtained by solving the inequality i>10000-2*i. The exact result for real numbers would be i>3333.333. But In this case i>3333 implies values greater than 3333 starting at 3334, because these distributions are constructed with natural integers from 1 to 4999. When i is 3334 or greater, all values of j will be 3332 or less, and always less than the two values of i that are equal. The resulting code looks like this:

```
expected_a= [[(5000-(i/2)),(5000-(i/2)),i] for i in simulations_ if i<3334]

for i in expected_a:
    x_a = sum([(o-e)**2./e for o,e in zip(simulated,i)])
    x_list.append(x_a)

expected_b = [[(5000-(i/2)),i,(5000-(i/2))] for i in simulations_ if i<3334]
  
for j in expected_b:
    x_b = sum([(o-e)**2./e for o,e in zip(simulated,j)])
    x_list.append(x_b)

expected_c = [[i,(5000-(i/2)),(5000-(i/2))] for i in simulations_ if i<3334]

for k in expected_c:
    x_c = sum([(o-e)**2./e for o,e in zip(simulated,k)])
    x_list.append(x_c)

expected_d= [[(10000-(2*i)),i,i] for i in simulations if i>3333]

for l in expected_d:
    x_d = sum([(o-e)**2./e for o,e in zip(simulated,l)])
    x_list.append(x_d)

expected_e= [[i,(10000-(2*i)),i] for i in simulations if i>3333]

for m in expected_e:
    x_e = sum([(o-e)**2./e for o,e in zip(simulated,m)])
    x_list.append(x_e)

expected_f= [[i,i,(10000-(2*i))] for i in simulations if i>3333]

for n in expected_f:
    x_f = sum([(o-e)**2./e for o,e in zip(simulated,n)])
    x_list.append(x_f)

def forecast():
    if all(i>cr for i in x_list):
```

This seems to have solved the problem.

Comment: Without looking at the code and going into details, a statistical tests assesses a null hypothesis that is of interest to the researcher, so you need to know which hypothesis you want to test, and we cannot tell you this.

Comment: You’re right. I was not precise about my interest. I only wrote “infer”. I am sorry about that. I am interested in forecasting a most likely winner, even if just more slightly likely, based on the results, within a level of significance. The null hypotheses should therefore be results that end in a tie (which means it is not possible to forecast a winner). My suggestion is based on this interest. It seems to work.  But I just feel unsure about the logic.

Comment: By the way, the way I see it, ties are both possible when the frequency for "tie" is higher and the distribution is significant, and when the null hypotheses for not being able to call a winner is true. Therefore, according to my logic, there are two alternative ways to forecast a tie, whereas it is only possible to forecast a winner when the simulated distribution is significant, and there is one of the frequencies that is higher than the others.